# Is there a shorter way to write this?

Tags: java

I'm wondering if it's possible to write this in one-liner form.

```
if (config.getBoolean("storecommands.use-time")) {
    out.println("[" + (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date()) + "]: " + e.getMessage());
 else {
     out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 out.close();
```

I thought maybe something like this:

```
(config.getBoolean("storecommands.use-time")) ? first : last;
```

but then I remembered that that only works for setting variables.

Does anyone know if something like the first block of code can be written in one line w/o brackets, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Nothing at all, it works fine, I'm just wondering if it's *possible*. Perhaps I posted this on the wrong website? Sorry. If so, I'll delete.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You can't use `? :` with methods declared with a `void` return type.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What??? Could you cite the JLS, please. Or ajust admit it's nonsense.

Comment: Can I know why I was down-voted? If I posted this on the wrong site, I said I would delete it - plain and simple (can't now), and as far as I know, this isn't a detrimental question to the community..

Comment: @jdersen I didn't downvote you, but I can imagine someone gets upset when he reads unfounded claims like "?: works only for setting veriables".

Comment: @Ingo That's what I thought it was for! D:

Comment: @ingo See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) entry in the JLS, which says `It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.`

Comment: @jdersen, I believe i answered your question nicely.

Comment: @OrelEraki You did, I'm waiting for the time to finish until I can accept. :)

Comment: @jdersen, More important, did you understood my explanation ?

Comment: @OrelEraki Yes I did, it was very clear.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is correct, but how is this relevant here?

Comment: @ingo I was replying to Elliot's comment to use the ternary. If they were proposing to use it as `(condition) ? out.println(..) : out.println(..)`, it would not compile, assuming `out.println()` is a `void` method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ohh, I see now. But Elliot didn't suggest that. We can assume he had something in mind like shown in the replies.

Comment: @Ingo After they've posted a clarification, sure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, But readability is more important than length (In reasonable amount).

Additionally, I've used a ternary condition that will inject the formatted date **OR** string empty, thus allowing us to freely add `e.getMessage` Once.

```
out.println((config.getBoolean("storecommands.use-time") ? "[" + (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date()) + "]: " : "") + e.getMessage());
out.close();
```

Comment: +1 for using e.getMessage() only once. There are two replies that use it twice.

Comment: @Ingo, Thanks, it is the shortest one and in purpose i didn't formatted it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String foo(boolean b) {
    if(b) {
        return new String("[" + (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date()) + "]: ");
    } else {
        return "";
}
```

Then simply do this:

```
out.println(foo(config.getBoolean("storecommands.use-time") + e.getMessage());
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary like so (but it's ugly, and you still need a close() or a flush()).

```
// Construct this constant date format elsewhere, and save the referene!
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
// This ternary is ugly, but possible.
out.println((config.getBoolean("storecommands.use-time") ? 
    "[" + df.format(new Date()) + "]: " : "")
    + e.getMessage());
out.close(); // <-- might prefer flush() there.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not one line, but two lines:

```
out.println(config.getBoolean("storecommands.use-time")) ? 
"[" + (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date()) 
+ "]: " + e.getMessage()) : e.getMessage());

out.close();
```

But that is possibly the worst thing I've ever seen and you should never ever do this in production code. If you do I will know, and we will find you.

Comment: Ugh, good lord that's bad too. They're all bad. Cleanse them with fire. Did someone down vote for a little joke in a useful answer?

Comment: Why do you repeat yourself with `e.getMessage()`? This is what is bad with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the conditional operator here, but it'll probably come at the cost of readability, so I would reconsider. In any case, you can do:

```
boolean b = config.getBoolean("storecommands.use-time");
String message = e.getMessage();    

out.println(b ? 
                "[" + (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date()) + "]: " + message
              :
                message);
```

Writing this all on one line is simply a bad idea, so I've split it up to span multiple lines.

Comment: The way you do it is indeed not very readable. I'd ask myself why would someone write it in such a way as to write `e.getMessage()` twice?

Comment: @Ingo The replies that use it only once also concatenate it with an empty String.

Comment: @Ingo I've factored out the `e.getMessage()`. I'm not sure there's much more that can be done. I think the downvote is excessive here.

Comment: +1 You could even rename `b` into `useTime` but it may make the code more readable so I'm not sure...